# Getting error when insert birth date into a database

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, contactscontract

I'm trying to insert contacts details to a MySQL database,

**Here is my code :**

```
public void SyncContact(){

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
    HashMap<String,String> hashmap_contactList = new HashMap<String, String>();

    String id="";
    String name="";
    String  mobileNo="";
    String  emailContact="";
    String orgName="";
    String title="";
    String note="";
    String street="";
    String dob="";
    int i = 0;
       while (phones.moveToNext()) {
         id = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
         name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
         mobileNo = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

        Cursor emailCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
        if(emailCur.getCount()>0) {
        while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
            emailContact = emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
            String emailType = emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));
        }
        }else{
            emailContact="";
        }
        emailCur.close();
        String orgWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
        String[] orgWhereParams = new String[]{id,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
        Cursor orgCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,null, orgWhere, orgWhereParams, null);
        if(orgCur.getCount()>0) {
            if (orgCur.moveToFirst()) {
                orgName = orgCur.getString(orgCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.DATA));
                title = orgCur.getString(orgCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE));
            }
        }else{
            orgName="";
            title="";
        }
        orgCur.close();
        String[] noteWhereParams = new String[]{id,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
        Cursor noteCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, orgWhere, noteWhereParams, null);
        if(noteCur.getCount()>0) {
           if (noteCur.moveToFirst()) {
               note = noteCur.getString(noteCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.NOTE));
           }
        }else{
           note="";
        }
        noteCur.close();
        String[] addrWhereParams = new String[]{id,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
        Cursor addrCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,null, orgWhere, addrWhereParams, null);
        if(addrCur.getCount()>0){
        while(addrCur.moveToNext()) {

             street = addrCur.getString(addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET));
        }
        }else {
            street="";
        }
        addrCur.close();

        String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {id,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};

        Cursor dobCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, orgWhere, selectionArgs, null);
        if(dobCur.getCount()>0) {
            if (dobCur.moveToFirst()) {
                dob = dobCur.getString(dobCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.DATA));
            }
        }else {
            dob="";
        }
        dobCur.close();

        if(!hashmap_contactList.containsKey(name)){
            hashmap_contactList.put(name, " ");
            System.out.println("!! Contact ID is : "  + id);
            System.out.println("!! Contact Name is : "  + name);
            System.out.println("!! Contact Number is : " + mobileNo);
            System.out.println("!!prepare Email " + emailContact );
            System.out.println("!!prepare  Comapny name:" + orgName);
            System.out.println("!!prepare Designation :" + title);
            System.out.println("!!prepare Note :" + note);
            System.out.println("!!prepare Street:" + street);
            System.out.println("!!hello dob :" + dob);

            try{
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("contact_uniqueid",id);
                jsonObject.put("contact_name",name);
                jsonObject.put("contact_number",mobileNo);
                jsonObject.put("email",emailContact);
                jsonObject.put("oraganization",orgName);
                jsonObject.put("job_title",title);
                jsonObject.put("address",street);
                jsonObject.put("note",note);
                jsonObject.put("dob",dob);

                ja.put(jsonObject);
                mainjson.put("data",ja);

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
        }
       }
    phones.close();
    System.out.println("!!json " + mainjson);
    try {
        Log.d("!!!main_json", mainjson.toString(1));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }        

    ContactSync contactSync = new ContactSync();
    contactSync.execute();
}

public class ContactSync extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

    String JsonString;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(str_url);
        try{
            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(mainjson.toString());
            post.setEntity(entity);
            post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            BasicResponseHandler handler = new BasicResponseHandler();

            String response = client.execute(post, handler);
            System.out.println("!!Response : " + response);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            System.out.println("!!Response " + jsonObject);
            System.out.println("!! " + jsonObject.getString("data"));
            JSONObject success_status = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
            System.out.println("!!Succes MSg :" + success_status.getString("success"));

            if(success_status.getString("success").toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
            {
                System.out.println("Response after data inserted....."+success_status.getString("success").toString());
                CommonFunction.saveSharedPreference(CommonFunction.contactsync_flag, "1", SplashActivity.this);
            }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("!! : "+e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("!!!!!!manishhhhhhh......" );
            }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
```

**And the API Code is :**

```
public function temp(){
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $boolean = TRUE;
            $data = array();
            $contact_data = $_POST['data'];
            $i=0;

        foreach($contact_data AS $row){
            $fields['contact_uniqueid']=$row['contact_uniqueid'];
            $fields['contact_name']=$row['contact_name'];
            $fields['contact_number']=$row['contact_number'];
            $fields['email']=$row['email'];
            $fields['oraganization']=$row['oraganization'];
            $fields['job_title']=$row['job_title'];
            $fields['address']=$row['address'];
            $fields['note']=$row['note'];
            $fields['dob']=$row['dob'];
            $data[$i] = $fields;
            $i++;
        }

            $this->express_model->set_table('contact_list');
            $data_obj = $this->express_model->saveBatch($data);

        if  ($boolean == TRUE)
        {
            $final_data['data']['success'] = 'true';
            $final_data['data']['message'] = 'Data inserted successfully';
            print_r(json_encode($final_data));
        }
            exit;    
}
```

All contacts details are inserted into the database and I have to get "true" in the JSON response but I'm getting this error:

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
```

and I use PHP API written in codeigniter.

Comment: What is the structure of the birth field in your database and how do you insert?

Comment: Where is the error? Are you using Java or PHP??

Comment: i took varchar datatype for birth date field and i use PHP for API

Comment: That is not an error. It's html, which probably makes an error if you actually render the page. Use Postman to test your api before you write it in Java

Comment: i tested api in postman, it's work fine in postman but it give an html line when i run java code

Answer (score 0):

check the data type into your database schema and try to insert the appropriate value..

Mostly it happen when we use DateTime data type for fields